# Conditionally running git hooks with husky

Tags: git, lerna, pre-commit, husky

We have a frontend webpack powered project running that has husky (it's yorkie to be precise since we use lerna). We have a very big collection of unit test suites, so we would like to improve the pre-commit hooks to not run the tests when only non-code files have been changed, e.g. config.json or README.md. Does anybody know a ready-made solution for that or do we have to write our own shell script that checks the git status? Thankful for links, patterns or best practices advice.

Comment: In `pre-commit`, use `git diff --cached --name-status` to get the files to be committed.

Comment: Yes, already thought about that. Just hoped there was something like a plugin or npm package that has that logic already

Comment: I recently got something like this working for linting, with https://www.npmjs.com/package/lint-staged . What tests are affected by what changes depends on architecture of your project, so it's likely this problem doesn't have a neat solution somebody could put out as ready to use package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we couldn't find any ready-made solution we solved it like this:

```
# check-files.sh

code_files_count=`git --no-pager diff --name-only --cached |
grep -E "packages\/(?:package1|package2)\/.+\.(?:js|ts|vue|scss|html)$" |
wc -l`
        
if [ $code_files_count == 0 ]
then
    exit 0
fi
        
exit 1
```

And then in package.json

```
"precommit": "./check-files.sh || npm run test:unit"
```